# Understanding the theme .sty file of beamer

Tags: beamer, packages, themes

I am trying to add progress bar on the theme I am using but very unsure how sty file is working, so I have no idea where to adjust. Can anyone help me understand how this theme is working?

I want to add this smoothbar
[image]

slide tex file:

```
\documentclass[
11pt,notheorems,hyperref={pdfauthor=whatever}
]{beamer}

\input{loadslides.tex} % Loads packages and some defined commands
```

loadslides.tex:

```
\RequirePackage{palatino}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{styles/elegantmacros}
\usefolder{styles}
\usetheme[style=blue]{elegant}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

Outer theme sty file the `\usepackage{styles/elegantmacros}` refers to is

```
\mode<presentation>
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% Set Margins around frame title
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace{1cm} \color{primary}\insertframetitle \par\vskip1pt \color{secondary}{\small\insertframesubtitle} \vspace*{0.5cm}}

% Automatic Frame Titles
\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{%
    \global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar%
    \bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \ifx\insertframetitle\empty
    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\empty
      \ifx\insertsubsection\empty 
        \frametitle{\insertsectionhead}
      \else
        \frametitle{\insertsectionhead}\framesubtitle{\insertsubsectionhead}
      \fi  
    \else
        \frametitle{\insertsectionhead} %If frame title is empty but subtitle is specified by user, insert section as frametitle   
    \fi  
    \else       
    \fi
 }{}

%\setbeamertemplate{framesubtitle}{\color{primary}\insertframesubtitle\par\vskip6pt \vspace*{0.5cm}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% Footer

% Set Margins around footer
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\hspace*{10mm}
{\scshape \insertshortauthor \hfill \insertshorttitle \hfill \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}
\hspace*{10mm} 
\vspace*{0.6cm}
}

\mode<all>
```

macros

```
\mode<presentation>

\mode<presentation>

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% Define folder tree
\def\beamer@calltheme#1#2#3{%
    \def\beamer@themelist{#2}
    \@for\beamer@themename:=\beamer@themelist\do
    {\usepackage[{#1}]{\beamer@themelocation/#3\beamer@themename}}}

\def\usefolder#1{
    \def\beamer@themelocation{#1}
  }
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  
\mode<all>
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to understand all the details from your theme, the one important thing is that your theme does not define a headline.

This means you could just load the `smoothbars` outer theme before your custom theme:

```
\documentclass[
11pt,notheorems,hyperref={pdfauthor=whatever}
]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}

\input{loadslides.tex} % Loads packages and some defined commands

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]